# Route53 Hosted Zone Subdomain Creation

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have successfully migrated my DNS from godaddy to use Amazon's Route53 to manage my DNS. My question is when creating subdomains do I have to create their own hosted zone or just an A RecordSet inside the parent domains hosted zone?

I am going to experiment it with a little but just thought I may get an answer here before I figure it out with a little experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set up a subdomain called subdomain.example.com, you simply add the relevant record inside the example.com zone. That single hosted zone is all you need.

As an example, you might want to point subdomain.example.com to a certain IP address. All you need to do is create a new record set, put "subdomain" in the Name field, enter the IP address in the Value field, and save. No additional NS records are required.

Comment: Good answer. I'd note that you *can* make a separate zone if you want. We do that for large zones like `internal.example.com` we want to logically separate via delegation.

Comment: ok, thats great. I will try it out.